# Is it possible to make a Hadoop MapReduce Job write one file per key?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to use Hadoop for a glorified job tracker and I need to be able to write a single file per output key. Furthermore I need the file to be named the same thing as the text of the key and I want the file to be exactly the value associated with that output key. Is this possible? How?

Comment: see the output multiplexing part here : http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat , but this would require you to use the old mapred API.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) for using a custom file name based on the key sent to the reducer.

Comment: This gets me really close! But I think I need just a bit more help. Right now I'm writing to files with arbitrary names - except that they all end with "-m-00000". How do I remove this extra part?

Comment: Oops.. and I found one more thing. I can make the name of the file what I want it to be (except for the -m-00000 at the end), but the content of the file needs to be just the value (ByteArray) rather than `key.toString +"\t"+ value.toString`. Any ideas?